# ¿Se puede usar "npm ls" con un parámetro?

Tags: nodejs, npm, redux

Acabo de instalar un par de paquetes para empezar a trabajar con [Redux](http://redux.js.org/):

```
npm install --no-optional --save-dev redux-devtools
npm install --no-optional --save react-redux
```

Como quería comprobar que lo había instalado todo bien, hice [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls):

```
$ npm ls react redux
MyProject@ /home/me/projects/myproject
├── react@15.3.0 
└── redux@3.5.2
```

Así que sí, ¡están instalados!

Sin embargo, me quedé con la duda de si hay alguna manera de ver qué paquetes instalados empiezan con "re".

Estos dos comandos:

```
npm ls re*
npm ls re
```

Devuelven el mismo error:

```
MyProject@ /home/me/projects/myproject
└── (empty)

npm ERR! code 1
```

Pensé en [`npm search`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search) para hacer esto, pero por lo que entiendo este comando busca los paquetes disponibles para ser instalados, no los que tienes ya instalados en tu máquina:

```
$ npm search re*
NAME             DESCRIPTION                                           AUTHOR   
requirements-txt requirements-txt - generate requirements.txt (python… =russiani
```

Por tanto mi duda es: ¿hay alguna forma de usar `npm ls` para extraer el listado de paquetes instalados cuyo nombre encaja con un patrón dado?

Nótese que ya lo pregunté en Stack Overflow: [npm ls matching a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39147687/1983854) y la respuesta `npm ls | grep ...` que me dieron no me convence pues pregunto por el comando `npm ls` específicamente, sin recurrir a pipes.

Answer (score 1):

> La respuesta `npm ls | grep` que me dieron **no me convence**, pues pregunto por el comando npm ls específicamente, sin recurrir a pipes.

¿Alguna razón en particular por la cual no aprovechar pipeling? Siendo esto tan simple como lo siguiente:

**Bash**

```
npm ls | grep <palabra>
```

**Powershell**

```
npm ls | select-string "<palabra>"
```

**Dos**

```
npm ls | findstr "<palabra>
```

Answer (score 0):

La salida de `npm ls` es "grepeable" como casi todo en linux.

```
npm ls | grep re
```